# PHP Simple Header Injection Prevention

Tags: php, email, code-injection

I am trying to prevent mail header injection by looping through all the _POST data but the variables are not passing my validation. I have a few "date" fields that include slashes and some of the fields might be blank. Not sure if that would have anything to do with it. Can anyone see the problem with my logic? I keep getting my "fail" message. Thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $boolValidateOK = 1;

    function safe( $name ) {
       return( str_ireplace(array( "\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:" ), "", $name ) );
    }

    foreach($_POST as $value){
        if(!safe($value)){
            $boolValidateOK = 0;
        }else{
            $boolValidateOK = 1;
        }
    }

    if($boolValidateOK == 1){

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $to...etc
        $subject...etc
        $message...etc

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        $success_message = "win";
    }else{
        $error_message = "fail";
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a useless and potentially harmful security "improvement" to me. Unless you're allowing your users to specify mail headers directly, there's no point in doing this other than potentially butcher user input.

Comment: I am new to programming. Can you please explain how? How would I go about preventing header injection then?

Comment: Well, where's the rest of the code (ie: the stuff you replaced with `etc`)? It doesn't sound like something you *need* to do

Comment: Sorry, the rest of the code is a 15+ field mail form.

Comment: Well, how do you set `$headers`?

Comment: I updated my code to show what I am setting as my `$headers`. There is no From: or Cc: needed.

Comment: ... or you could switch to using PHPMailer or Swiftmailer and avoid having to try and design your own (in)security system...

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Never heard of it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is unnecessary. Note PHP's `mail()` function signature:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message 
              [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

The recipient is the second argument. The headers are all in the fourth argument. The contents of `$message` or `$subject` are not going to magically "spill over" to the other arguments.

Since your `$headers` doesn't depend on user input, it doesn't really matter if the user has entered. No such "injection" is possible. All you're doing is butchering the message.

PS: This code is wrong:

```
foreach($_POST as $value){
    if(!safe($value)){
        $boolValidateOK = 0;
    }else{
        $boolValidateOK = 1;
    }
}

if($boolValidateOK == 1){
```

Think about it. Let's say all your post values are not "safe," but the last one iterated is. It will then overwrite `$boolValidateOK` to `1`, and that's the value it will retain by the time the loop has ended.

Also, PHP does have a boolean type. If you have a bool, set them to `true` or `false` instead of 1 and 0. It's clearer.

---

Regardless, I would recommend using something like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). The native `mail()` function is very awkward to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what your saying is I can scrap all that code and just have `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` send on `'submit'`?

Comment: @user1738750 There are still some things you might want to make sure of, eg: the email is valid, there are not a ton of recipients (eg: `"user@abc.com , user2@abc.com ..."`), the message body is stripped of potentially malicious code (that would affect the recipient(s), not you), etc.

Comment: The form will only be sent to 1 static email address. How would you go about preventing malicious code?

Comment: @user1738750 You could use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all HTML from the message.